# How to compile only the compression module of Hadoop?

Tags: maven, hadoop, compilation, compression, codec

I'm trying to develop a new codec compression for Hadoop. First of all I'd know if there is same tutorial for implementing a new codec in Hadoop. Hence, I've tried to edit several default codec such as Snappy or Deflate, by changing final extension, for example I've changed the extension of Deflate with ".dummy".
But the very problem is due to compilation phase because to upload the new codec code in Hadoop. In order to upload correctly the code, a new recompiling is made each time that i want check new editing in code.

How can I accelerate this process?

I tried to execute the compilation with:

1. `mvn package -Pdist,native` one time for editing in code,
2. `mvn compile -pl Hadoop-common-project`
3. `mvn install -pl Hadoop-common-project`

but previous test worst result have been reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by compiling the package located in Hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common. In previous folder a pom.xml file is located. After that I run the mvn compilation by following:

> mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests

Hence, I copied the jar located in **target** folder to $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common. Previous steps is able to us use our codec in Hadoop after that it is specified in mapred-site.xml file.